# How to sum elements of N lists in python?

Tags: python, numbers

I have a list of tuples of lists... :

```
lst = [(['a', 1], ['b', 2]), (['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5])]
```

And I want to get the sum of index[1] of every lists in each tuples (first tuple = 3, second tuple = 12)
result can look like this:

```
['ab', 3]
['cde', 12]
```

I tried this :

```
for tuples in lst:
    total = [x + y for (x, y) in zip(*tuples)]
    print(total)
```

but if a tuple has more than 2 values (like the second one) I will get a value error.

I need to get the sum of every lists no matter the number of lists in each tuples

So I tried this instead:

```
for tuples in lst:
    sum = [sum(x) for x in zip(*tuples)]
```

But I get a **TypeError: 'list' object is not callable**

Any ideas ?

Comment: In the second code, the fact that you used `sum` as variable name caused your error. I replaced the others `list`/`sum` but left this one for reproducibility of the error

Comment: Also, I'm not sure what you want to do with the output, but `print` should really never be used for its property to yield elements. Use a generator, or collect in a list.

Comment: I don't use this names in my code, it was for the example, I didn't know it was so important... thank you !

Comment: btw, I will not use prints, I only need to know the sum of each lists to sort them afterwards. thanks for the advices

Comment: Ok, then you don't care about joining the strings? What about directly sorting with a key: `sorted(lst, key=lambda x: sum(list(zip(*x))[1]))`?

Comment: yeah, I only need to know if the sum of the ints of each lists are above or below a certain number. In my main code, I have list that has an unknown number of tuples, which has a unknown number of lists. And I need to only get the tuples which have a total value <= 500, for example. (I hope this is pretty clear)

Comment: Then you don't even need to sort, just filter: `[x for x in lst if sum(list(zip(*x))[1])<=500]`

Comment: ok, this example is perfect.. that's all i needed, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply this:

```
L = [(['a', 1], ['b', 2]), (['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5])]

for t in L:
    s = ''.join(x[0] for x in t)
    S = sum(x[1] for x in t)
    print([s, S])
```

and refrain to define variable names using python keywords...

Answer (score 2):

Check this out.

```
result = [("".join(list(zip(*tup))[0]), sum(list(zip(*tup))[1])) for tup in lst]
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps

```py
lst = [ (['a', 1], 
         ['b', 2]), 
         
        (['c', 3], 
         ['d', 4], 
         ['e', 5]) ]

for i in lst:
  print["".join([d for d in zip(*i)][0]), sum([d for d in zip(*i)][1])]
```

The problem with the first code was; You had `x+y`, it will only work for the first iteration of the loop, cause there are only 2 values to unpack. but it won't work for the second iteration.

And the problem with the second code you had was, that you were trying to add a type `int` and type `str` together

- *Just to avoid the confusion, I'm renaming the variable `list` to `lst`*

Answer (score 1):

Here is an idea, use a nested list comprehension with `zip` and a custom function to sum or join:

```
lst = [(['a', 1], ['b', 2]), (['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5])]

def sum_or_join(l):
    try:
        return sum(l)
    except TypeError:
        return ''.join(l)
    
out = [[sum_or_join(x) for x in zip(*t)] for t in lst]
```

Or if you really have always two items in the inner tuples, and always `('string', int)`:

```
out = [[f(x) for f, x in zip((''.join, sum), zip(*t))]
       for t in lst]
```

Output: `[['ab', 3], ['cde', 12]]`

Answer (score 1):

This should be clear and straightforward.

```
A = [(['a', 1], ['b', 2]), (['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5])]

result = []
for tup in A:
    char, value = "", 0
    for x, y in tup:
        char += x
        value += y
    result.append([char, value])
print(result)
```

Using `zip`:

```
result = []
for tup in A:
    tmp = []
    for x in zip(*tup):
        if type(x[0]) == str:
            tmp.append(''.join(x))
        elif type(x[0]) == int:
            tmp.append(sum(x))
    result.append(tmp)
print(result)
```

Sample O/P:

```
[['ab', 3], ['cde', 12]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Following one-liner produces desired `[('ab', 3), ('cde', 12)]` in result

```
lst = [(['a', 1], ['b', 2]), (['c', 3], ['d', 4], ['e', 5])] # don't use list 
                                                             # as variable name
# One-liner using builtin functions sum, list and Walrus operator
result = [(''.join(p[0]), sum(p[1])) for sublist in lst if (p:=list(zip(*sublist)))]
```

Note following should not be used as variable names since conflict with popular builtin functions:

- sum
- list

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
result = [[''.join([x for x,y in item]),sum([y for x,y in item])] for item in lst]
```